# Simple Structure in C - Help Needed

Tags: c, struct

I am not sure where am I going wrong with the following structure in C. Can you guys let me know What am I doing wrong and what would be the best approach.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
typedef struct
{
char *name;
float gpa;
int courseNo;
} STUDENT;

void createStudent(STUDENT s, char *n, float gpa, int course);

int main(void)
{
struct STUDENT s;
createStudent(s, "Dummy", 3.8f, 203);
printf("Name = %s\n", s.name);
printf("GPA = %3.1f\n", s.gpa);
printf("Course No. = %d\n", s.courseNo);
return 0;
}

void createStudent(STUDENT s, char *n, float gpa, int course)
{
  strcpy(s.name, n);
  s.gpa = gpa;
  s.courseNo = course;
 }
```

Comment: `createStudent()` only obtains a local copy, use `STUDENT* s` with `->` instead of `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    float gpa;
    int courseNo;
} STUDENT;

void createStudent(STUDENT* s, char *n, float gpa, int course);

int main(void)
{
    STUDENT s;
    createStudent(&s, "Dummy", 3.8f, 203);
    printf("Name = %s\n", s.name);
    printf("GPA = %3.1f\n", s.gpa);
    printf("Course No. = %d\n", s.courseNo);
    return 0;
}

void createStudent(STUDENT* s, char *n, float gpa, int course)
{
    s->name = malloc((strlen(n)+1) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(s->name, n);
    s->gpa = gpa;
    s->courseNo = course;
 }
```

Comment: now it says, 's' in the function must be of a modifiable value. How do I resolve this?

Comment: I corrected a semicolon error. This compiles and produces correct results for me. What is your compile statement?

Comment: Now, I see what u r saying. It worked!! However, there is one red underline under '=' sign. it says "Error, a value of type (void*) cannot be assign to a value of type (char*). but, it works.

Comment: I think that error will probably go away if you add a cast `(char *)` in front of the `malloc`. However, my understanding is that it is custom in Standard C to NOT cast malloc. Maybe you're using a C++ compiler?

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the `STUDENT` object by value, not by reference, so any changes that you make to it in your `createStudent` function do not effect `s`. Pass a pointer instead.

Normally whenever you pass a variable to a function, the variable's value is copied into the appropriate argument. This argument variable, however, is a separate variable from the one you passed however. By using pointers, you are essentially telling the function the *identity* of your variable, rather than just what value it holds.

As @simonc pointed out, there is one more problem in your code. When you call `strcpy` in your function, the pointer you are writing to (`s.name`) is unitialized, meaning that when you assign to its data via `strcpy` you are overwriting random memory, which is just asking for problems. You should allocate the memory with `malloc` before writing to it.

Here is the completed code:

```
void createStudent(STUDENT *s, char *n, float gpa, int course)
{ 
    s->name = malloc(strlen(n) + 1); // +1 for null terminator
    strcpy(s->name, n);
    s->gpa = gpa;
    s->courseNo = course;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
createStudent (&s, other args ... )
```

Note that you should deallocate the memory when you are done like so:

```
free(s.name);
```

but only when you don't plan on using the object any more.

Comment: 's' in the line, it says it must be a modifiable value    s->name = malloc(strlen(n + 1));

Comment: when i try to compile i am getting this error on the malloc line... error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value. How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

### Try this insteed

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
struct student
{
char name[20];
int age;
char branch[10];
char gender;
};
struct student s1;
s1.age=18;
strcpy(s1.name:"viraaj");
printf("name of student 1:%s\n",s1.name);
printf("age of student 1:%d\n",s1.age);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).